# How to create User in SalesForce through Resut API?

Tags: java, salesforce

I am working on SalersForce I want to create a User in SalesForce by using Java,How can I do that and what is the steps I have to follow. any one please help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might help get you started, "Create Users Automatically Through the REST API"  http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/workbook_security/Content/create_users_2.htm